# Postgres using seq scan with filter on indexed column + EXISTS on related table

Tags: postgresql, optimization, postgresql-9.6

I've following query which takes about 25-35 seconds to execute:

```
EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers, format text) SELECT booking.*
FROM booking
WHERE booking.reference_number = '9999999999' OR booking.booking_id = '9999999999' OR 
    (
        EXISTS (
            SELECT * FROM booking_customer 
            WHERE booking_customer.booking_id = booking.booking_id AND 
                (booking_customer.email = '9999999999' OR booking_customer.phone = '9999999999') AND 
                booking_customer.deleted = false
        )
    );
```

The explain output is here: https://explain.depesz.com/s/RPNV

As visible from the plan, there is sequence scan done on booking table, inspite of filtering on indexed columns - `reference_number` and `booking_id`. The `booking_customer` table is properly using index scan though.

Is it something to do with `EXISTS` or `OR` clauses there?

My table structure is as below:

```
                              Table "public.booking"
        Column         |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default
-----------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 deleted               | boolean                  |           |          |
 booking_id            | character varying        |           | not null |
 reference_number      | character varying        |           |          |
 booking_owner         | character varying        |           |          |
 checkin_date          | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 checkout_date         | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 status                | character varying        |           |          |
 hold_till             | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 version               | integer                  |           | not null |
 comments              | text                     |           |          |
 extra_information     | json                     |           |          |
 cancellation_reason   | character varying        |           |          |
 cancellation_datetime | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 created_at            | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | now()
 modified_at           | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | now()
Indexes:
    "booking_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (booking_id)
    "ix_booking_reference_number" UNIQUE, btree (reference_number)
    "idx_booking_checkin_date" btree (checkin_date)
    "idx_booking_checkout_date" btree (checkout_date)
    "ix_booking_status" btree (status)
    "trgm_booking_ref_num" gist (reference_number gist_trgm_ops)
```

And customer table:

```
                          Table "public.booking_customer"
        Column         |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default
-----------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 deleted               | boolean                  |           |          |
 customer_id           | character varying        |           | not null |
 booking_id            | character varying        |           | not null |
 first_name            | character varying        |           |          |
 last_name             | character varying        |           |          |
 gender                | character varying        |           |          |
 age                   | integer                  |           |          |
 nationality           | character varying        |           |          |
 phone                 | character varying        |           |          |
 email                 | character varying        |           |          |
 gst_addr_field1       | character varying        |           |          |
 gst_addr_field2       | character varying        |           |          |
 gst_addr_city         | character varying        |           |          |
 gst_addr_state        | character varying        |           |          |
 gst_addr_country      | character varying        |           |          |
 gst_pincode           | character varying        |           |          |
 legal_name            | character varying        |           |          |
 created_at            | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | now()
 modified_at           | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | now()
Indexes:
    "booking_customer_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (customer_id, booking_id)
    "book_cust_idx" btree (booking_id, customer_id)
    "ix_booking_customer_email" btree (email)
    "ix_booking_customer_phone" btree (phone)
    "trgm_cust_last_name" gist (last_name gist_trgm_ops)
```

Details on total records in table are as follows:

```
db=> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM booking;
 count
--------
 958092
(1 row)

db=> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM booking_customer;
  count
---------
 2471445
(1 row)

db=> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM booking WHERE reference_number = '9999999999' OR booking_id = '9999999999';
 count
-------
     1
(1 row)

db=> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM booking_customer WHERE (email = '9999999999' OR phone = '9999999999') AND deleted = false;
 count
--------
 156377
(1 row)

db=> SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(booking_id)) FROM booking_customer WHERE (email = '9999999999' OR phone = '9999999999') AND deleted = false;
 count
-------
 65196
(1 row)
```

So ideally, I should have gotten `65196` rows as result, which may be seems good reason to use sequence scan. But, when I try with a different value of phone or email, which results in roughly 1300 rows, still it uses seq scan on booking table.

I ran vacuum analyze on both tables yesterday midnight only.

Is there a way to optimise this query?

**Postgres details:**

```
db=> SELECT version();
                                    version
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.6.12 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.9.3, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

**Update**:

Just tried with `UNION ALL`, and the performance is too good. As good, as it makes me wonder if the result is correct? Or is there some drawback. Because why would anyone do `OR` condition in `WHERE` clause ever?

Here's the new query:

```
EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers, format text) 
SELECT booking.*
FROM booking
WHERE booking.deleted = false AND booking.reference_number = '9999999999'
UNION ALL
    SELECT booking.*
    FROM booking
    WHERE booking.deleted = false AND booking.booking_id = '9999999999'
UNION ALL
    SELECT booking.*
    FROM booking
    WHERE booking.deleted = false AND EXISTS (
            SELECT * FROM booking_customer 
            WHERE booking_customer.booking_id = booking.booking_id AND 
                (booking_customer.email = '9999999999' OR booking_customer.phone = '9999999999') AND 
                booking_customer.deleted = false
        );
```

New plan is here: https://explain.depesz.com/s/aXMV

Answer (score 4):

The reason why the query is choosing a sequential scan on `booking` is because the estimated number of rows to be scanned is 478,187, and the entire table is 958,092.  That means that more than half of the table will need to be scanned anyways--might as well just do a sequential scan, rather than pull 478K rows out of the index, then go to the disk to pull the actual rows out.

Note also that the estimate is incorrect.  It estimates 478,187 rows, but there are actually only 61,695 rows -- the estimate is 7.8x off.  You may need to perform an `ANALYZE` on the `booking` table and try again.

However, to focus on the Sequential Scan is sort of misleading, as the bulk of the runtime is in the loop over Index Scan on `book_cust_idx` 958,047 times.  Each scan of the index takes 0.025ms, but after looping through it nearly 1M times, the duration adds up.  The reason why it loops 958,047 times is because for each row in `booking`, it needs to compare with the result of `EXISTS`.

You may be better off just doing a `JOIN`, so that the two tables are merged, rather than looped upon:

```
EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers, format text) SELECT b.*
FROM booking b
JOIN booking_customer bc ON b.booking_id=bc.booking_id
WHERE b.reference_number = '9999999999'
   OR b.booking_id = '9999999999'
   OR ((bc.email = '9999999999' OR bc.phone = '9999999999') AND NOT bc.deleted);
```

**UPDATE:**
Using a `UNION ALL` works as well, since the individual reference_number and booking_id columns are indexed, effectively partitioning the result set for faster retrieval

Comment: The join query do work faster for when actual row count is 61000. But when I change the filter param value, to match row count of only 500, the join query is significantly slow -> 600 msec (for `EXISTS` query) vs 7 sec (for `JOIN` query).

Comment: Could you include the new query performance and plan on your post?

Comment: https://explain.depesz.com/s/8Hyt -> for `EXISTS`

Comment: https://explain.depesz.com/s/nSYc -> for `JOIN`.

Comment: Note: I've changed value from `9999999999` to `99999`.

Comment: I'm doing `distinct on`, to only get distinct booking record from `join`.

Comment: For `99999`, the `EXISTS` is faster because there is theoretically less to loop through (though in actuality, it didn't have to loop at all -- and again, the statistics are over-estimated).  I don't know how your data is laid out, but I think it would be best to test with a more accurate set of data before choosing between `JOIN` and `EXISTS` (i.e., I don't think real phone numbers and emails will be `9999999999`, nor will they appear several times--they should be unique, right?)

Comment: I just tried with `UNION ALL` instead of `OR`, and I'm absolutely dumb-smacked by difference: less than `10 msec` for `99999`, and `2-3 sec` for `9999999999`. I'm wondering if it's correct. If `(actual time=0.022..2277.088 rows=61703 loops=1)` is matching in 2 queries, then can we assume they will give same results?

Comment: I've added the `UNION ALL` query in my question. Can you please verify if it's fine? Also, result wise is there going to be any difference between that and original query?

Comment: Hmm, I think that `UNION ALL` **could** work, but I also believe that the query you used for `UNION ALL` searches for a different set of data.  In the `EXISTS` query, you are looking for booking_id `OR` reference_number, but in the `UNION ALL` query, you are looking for (booking_id `OR` reference_number) `AND` not-deleted.  That extra search on `deleted` is going to change the plan and runtime

Comment: Yeah I missed `deleted` in original post. But I was having that in original query too. So the filter criteria is same.

Comment: If that’s the case, then it looks like `UNION ALL` is your best bet. The `OR` clauses in your original post line up well with your `UNION ALL` sub-queries. I will edit my post to include that as well

Comment: BTW, can you figure out why that looping problem doesn't happen in 3rd part of UNION query? It's the same EXISTS query only?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100934/discussion-between-richyen-and-rohit-jain).

Answer (score 0):

The part where it "is properly using index scan" is by far the slowest part of your original query.  Is your goal to get the performance to be better, or to force it to use some preconceived notion of what is "proper", even if that is very slow?

> Just tried with UNION ALL, and the performance is too good. As good,
>   as it makes me wonder if the result is correct? Or is there some
>   drawback. Because why would anyone do OR condition in WHERE clause
>   ever?

With the UNION ALL, you will get the same row of "booking" returned multiple times if it satisfies multiple branches of the query.  With your original query, it would not do that.  So if the first query is correct, then the second one is incorrect.  Whether this is incorrect in a way that actually matters to you is something only you can know.  You could change "UNION ALL" to "UNION", but then there is a possibility of being incorrect in a different way, by over-consolidating rows rather than duplicating them.  But if one of the columns you are selecting is the primary key, then over-consolidating should not be possible and I believe your two queries are formally identical.

Comment: What are ways to improve the initial query, instead of doing `EXISTS`? Given that join is also not helping. I was not aware of the loop part. And also time was not clear in the explain text plan. After going through it clearly, I understood the time taking part.

Comment: Another thing which confuses me is, if second part of query is time taking, how it worked fine in UNION ALL? Since third query in union is same -> `EXISTS`.

Comment: You could try `OR booking.booking_id in (select booking_customer.booking_id from booking_customer where ....)`

Comment: That screws up for large booking_id list.